# Unity3D, change only pitch in rotation of an object's transform

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

Good evening. I have one GameObject, and I need to change its pitch (and do not impact on its yaw and roll). I have a quaternion which stores rotation from which I need to get the needed pitch and set to my game object. But the operation of cast from a Quaternion to Euler angles is not unique (one quaternion can be reperesented as multiple triples of Euler angles). Is it possible to do this without cast to Euler angles?

Comment: _"But the operation of cast from a Quaternion to Euler angles is not unique"_ - the point of quaternions is that you **not** convert to euler angles in order to perform an additional rotation.  That can lead to inaccurate rotations and/or gimbal lock. Simply create another quaternion with the delta rotation and combine it with the original.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, either by manipulating the raw components of the quaternion (scary) or using one of unity's built-in functions for it

[Quaternion.AngleAxis()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.AngleAxis.html) - Probably what you're looking for, you can easily isolate the rotation to pitch only.

But there's lots more functions for similar things [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) under the "Static Methods" header.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine rotations like so (based on a [Unity example](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-operator_multiply.html)), in this case the current rotation with a delta pitch rotation:

```
public class Example2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    float rotateSpeed = 90;

    // Applies a rotation of 90 degrees per second around the X axis for pitch
    void Update()
    {
        float angle = rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.rotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.right);
    }
}
```